# printf() positional arguments with the left justify flag

Tags: c, printf

I have been trying to understand how to do left justification with positional arguments using the printf function.

When I use something like the following, I get no errors:

```
printf("This is a %2$*1$s width var\n", 10, "ten");
```

However, when I try to use the left justify flag, I get an error:

```
printf("This is a %-2$*1$s width var\n", 10, "ten");

ex3.c:11:2: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘$’ in format [-Wformat=]
```

It almost seems like the flag is not being recognized, and instead argument "-2" is being looked for.

Is there a way I can format the string in printf to subvert this issue while still using positional arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what `man printf` says (on a system with glibc):

> One can also specify explicitly which argument is taken, at each place where an argument is required, by writing **`%m$` instead of `%`** and `*m$` instead of `*`, where the decimal integer `m` denotes the position in the argument list of the desired argument, indexed starting from 1.

Or, if you prefer the standard, Posix says:

> Each conversion specification is introduced by the `'%'` character or by the character sequence `"%n$"`, after which the following appear in sequence...

In other words, you can't just throw the `2$` anywhere into the format. It needs to be right after the `%`:

```
printf("This is a %2$-*1$s width var\n", 10, "ten");
```

Comment: My `man printf` does not mention that. Is this a compiler-specific extension? (If so, which compiler)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: Posix says "Each conversion specification is introduced by the '%' character or by the character sequence "%n$", after which the following appear in sequence...". It's a library issue, not a compiler.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: ...and it is certainly implemented by both the GNU and the FreeBSD C libraries (which is used by Mac OS X), with appropriate documentation in their respective manpages. Which C library do you use?

Comment: ah yes, I see what you are referencing in the documentation. I admittedly feel that documentation makes a lot more sense though if you already understand what it means. It's phrased kind of oddly.

At any rate, Thanks so much for your help!